# how define both required and anyof properties in OpenAPI 3.0

Tags: json, swagger, schema, openapi

I am creating an OpenAPI 3 spec for an api which has object for which some property are required and for some they are anyof. When i create the spec as below it throws an error, which i am unable to fix.

```
EnrollementRequest:
      type: object
      properties:
        consent:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ConsentEnum"
        cid:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/CID'
        card:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Card'
        enrollmentDateTime :
          description: The date and time of enrollment with respective timezone
          format: date-time
          example: 2018-11-13T20:20:39+00:00
        campaign_code: 
          description: the campaign-code for which customer wants to enroll
          type: string
        offer_code:
          description: the offer-code for which customer wants to enroll
          type: string
        channelInfo:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Channel'
      required:
        - consent
        - cid
        - enrollmentDateTime
        - channelInfo
      anyOf:
        - campaign_code
        - offer_code
```

Swagger editor gives an error as below -

```
Errors

Structural error at components.schemas.EnrollementRequest.anyOf.0
should be object
Jump to line ...
Structural error at components.schemas.EnrollementRequest.anyOf.1
should be object
Jump to line ...
```

Upon using the suggestion as below

```
  anyOf:
    - required: [campaign_code]
    - required: [offer_code]
```

the validation error went away but the swagger editor schema / model view is not showing any content as below -

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem Arpit. Did you ever figure this out? I have two properties in my object and I need at least one of them to be set. The current OAS 3 documentation says the values in an `anyOf` must be OAS Schema objects, so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 5):

Right, `anyOf` must be a list of objects. Try this:

```
      anyOf:
        - required: [campaign_code]
        - required: [offer_code]
```

Alternativelly, to make it look better in the Swagger editor:

```
    EnrollementRequest:
      type: object
      properties:
        consent:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ConsentEnum"
        cid:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/CID'
        card:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Card'
        enrollmentDateTime :
          description: The date and time of enrollment with respective timezone
          format: date-time
          example: 2018-11-13T20:20:39+00:00
        channelInfo:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Channel'
      required:
        - consent
        - cid
        - enrollmentDateTime
        - channelInfo
      anyOf:
        - properties:
            campaign_code: 
              description: the campaign-code for which customer wants to enroll
              type: string
          required: [campaign_code] 
        - properties: 
            offer_code:
              description: the offer-code for which customer wants to enroll
              type: string
          required: [offer_code]
```

Comment: The validation error went away, but now the swagger editor doesn't recognize any content there. See the picture in the above question

Comment: @ArpitMittal I've added an alternative solution

Comment: It worked and shows in the schema, but the swagger is unable to generate the sample request body. Any ideas ?                                                                                        {
  "consent": "ACCEPTED",
  "cid": "AB5160001725799",
  "card": 1234123412341234,
  "enrollmentDateTime": {},
  "channelInfo": {
    "channel": "BOA",
    "operatorType": "Officer Id",
    "operatorId": "z56995909",
    "transitNumber": 12345
  }
}